# Show the existence of a sorting function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, order-theory, monotone-functions, sorting

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a totally ordered set. A sort for $f\in X^n$ is an element $g\in X^n$ satisfying

(i) $g$ is nondecreasing.

(ii) $ g=f\circ \sigma$ for some permutation $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to \{1,\dots,n\}$.

A sorting function for $X^n$ is a function $\Phi:X^n\to X^n$ such that $\Phi(f)$ is a sort for $f$, for each $f\in X^n$.

Am asked to show that there exists a sorting function for $X^n$.

**My attempt:**

By induction on $n$. If $n=1$ this is trivial. Suppose there exists a sorting function  $\Phi:X^n\to X^n$ for some $n\geq 1$.

Define the functions $\Gamma,\Delta:X^{n+1}\to X^{n+1}$ by
$$\Gamma(f)=\bigg(\Phi[f|_{\{1,\dots,n\}}],f(n+1)\bigg)$$

$$\Delta(f)=f\circ \pi$$

where $\pi:\{1,\dots,n+1\}\to \{1,\dots,n+1\}$ is the permutation defined by

$$\pi(i)=\begin{cases} 
      i & \text{if } \quad i<i_0 \\
      n+1 & \text{if } \quad i=i_0 \\
     i-1 & \text{if } \quad i>i_0 
   \end{cases}$$

where $i_0$ is the smallest element of the set $\big\{1\leq i\leq n:f(n+1)\leq f(i)\big\}$ if this set is nonempty, and $i_0:=n+1$ otherwise.

I claim that $\Phi':=\Delta\circ \Gamma$ is a sorting function for $X^{n+1}$. Since $\Phi[f|_{\{1,\dots,n\}}]=f|_{\{1,\dots,n\}}\circ \sigma$ for some permutation $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to \{1,\dots,n\}$ we see that $\Gamma(f)=f\circ \sigma'$ for some permutation $\sigma'$. Then

$$\Phi'(f)=(\Delta\circ \Gamma) (f)=f\circ \sigma'\circ\pi$$ for the permutation $\sigma'\circ\pi$. By considering the different cases with respect to $i_0$ we also see that $i\leq j$ implies $\Phi'(f)(i)\leq \Phi'(f)(j)$. Hence $\Phi'(f)$ statisfies (i) and (ii) for all $f\in X^{n+1}$ and so is indeed a sorting function for $ X^{n+1}$.

Is this correct?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it seems correct, however, I am not totally sure since I find it a bit convoluted. I think the proof becomes more concise using $\max$ instead of the smallest element that is larger than $f(n+1)$.

Let $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\text{argmax}_n(f):=\max f^{-1}(\max\{f(i):i\in[n]\})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f\in X^n$.
Now, proving via induction: as you wrote, the base case is trivial.

Suppose there exists a sorting function $sort_n$ for $X^n$ for some $n\geq1$. For every $f\in X^{n+1}$ define $\pi_f:[n+1]\rightarrow[n+1]$ such that $$\pi_f(k)=\begin{cases}n+1&\text{if }k=\text{argmax}_{n+1}(f)\\\text{argmax}_{n+1}(f)&\text{if }k=n+1\\k&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Also, for every $f\in X^{n+1}:\exists\sigma_f:[n]\rightarrow[n]$ such that $$sort_n(f|_{[n]})=f|_{[n]}\circ\sigma_f$$
Also, define for every $\sigma:[n]\rightarrow[n]$ the unique permutation $\sigma^*:[n+1]\rightarrow[n+1]$ such that $\sigma^*|_{[n]}=\sigma$.

Now define $sort_{n+1}(f):X^{n+1}\rightarrow X^{n+1}$ such that $$sort_{n+1}(f)=f\circ\pi_f\circ\sigma_{f\circ\pi_f}^*$$

(EDIT: as has been pointed out in the comments:
This is well-defined since although the permutation $\sigma_{f\circ\pi_f}^*$ isn't necessarily unique, the permutations only differ if there are mutliple elements which are the same which can be arbitrarily exchanged with eachother, however as equal elements are swapped, the result stays the same.)

Now, it is clear that $sort_{n+1}(f)|_{[n]}=sort_n(f\circ\pi_f|_{[n]})$, for which it is clear, that it is non-decreasing via induction hypothesis. It is also clear that $sort_{n+1}(f)(n+1)$ is the maximum via definition. Therefore, the whole element is non-decreasing. And since permutations are closed under composition, $sort_{n+1}$ is indeed a sorting function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this is correct as written. For example if I apply your sorting algorithm to $(2,4,3,1)\in\mathbb N^4$ I obtain $(2,3,1,4)$.

Comment: Instead I would define $sort_{n+1}(f):=\big(sort_n(f\circ\pi_f|_{[n]}), f(\pi_f(n+1)) \big)$

Comment: Then I think it works. The difference in words is that you place the largest element last and then sort the others. In my proof I sort the first n elements and then place the last element in the right index. So we interchanged the order. I agree that your approach seems more straightforward.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I corrected the subscript of $\sigma_f^*$ to $\sigma_{f\circ\pi_f}^*$. Now, it is correct.

Comment: I would also add that $sort_{n+1}(f)$ does not depend on the particular choice of $\sigma_f$, because for any choice we get $sort_{n+1}(f)=\big(sort_n(f\circ\pi_f|_{[n]}), f(\pi_f(n+1)) \big)$. This is important because there are possibly many choices for $\sigma_f$.

Comment: Well, yeah, but that would also be the case in your proof, I just added the subscript to be explicit about the dependence since the permutation ISN'T necessarily the same for every $f$.

Comment: My point is that for a given $f$ there can be multiple $\sigma_f$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. You are absolutely right. My point is, if you find that that is lacking in my proof, you should add that clarification to your proof as well since you implicitly assume the same thing in your definition of $\Phi'(f)$.

Comment: The difference is that my definition of $\Phi'(f):=(\Delta \circ \Gamma) (f)$ does not involve a choice. The choice of $\sigma$ is only made after to prove that (ii) is satisfied for some permutation. Your definition $sort_{n+1}(f):=f\circ\pi_f\circ\sigma_{f\circ\pi_f}^*$ involves a choice for $\sigma_f$, and so to be well-defined we must make sure that the definition does not depend on that choice. If you define $sort_{n+1}(f):=\big(sort_n(f\circ\pi_f|_{[n]}), f(\pi_f(n+1)) \big)$ then there is no choice involved. Just a small detail.

Comment: Ah, I see, you are right. Maybe change $\Phi'(f):=$ to $\Phi'(f)=$ then since $:=$ is usually left for definition, but you are not defining it, just establishing an equality. I was confused at least.

Comment: Yes you are right the definition is $\Phi':=\Delta\circ \Gamma$ so that $\Phi'(f)=(\Delta\circ \Gamma)(f)$ holds by definition. I made an edit to my post with the correction.